# Medium Power Charge Pumps

Tags: charge-pump, medical

I'm working on an MRI research project where I need to power my device with a single BNC cable.  Internally my device needs 15V, -8.5V, 5V, 3.3V and 1.2V supplies. The 15V, -8.5V and 1.2V only need 10mA each, but the other two need 500mA.

I can't use any inductors and LDOs will produce too much heat for the two big loads.  I have limited ways I can cool the device (can't find any magnet-less fans. :)  My existing design uses a 5V input (on the BNC) and I use 4 different groups of many small charge pumps in parallel to get to the other voltages.  At 5V the BNC is almost maxed out on current (BNCs are for signals of course but, this is crazy MRI land :)

I want to switch to a 16V supply:

- LDO down to 15V
- Invert and LDO down to -8.5V
- Step Down Pump to 8V and LDO to 5.0V
- Step Down Pump to 4V and LDO to 3.3V
- LDO down to 1.2V

The problem is all the parallel pumps to handle my two 500mA loads. Most commercial charge pumps that I have found, are meant for low current applications in the <50mA range.  This makes sense for the huge collection of devices that operate in this range and the fact that charge-pump efficiency suffers at higher currents.  Just switch to inductor based boost and buck converters, right?  Of course who thinks about MRI, other than folks like me who have to deal.

Has anyone had a good experience building a "medium current" charge pump?  As much as heat is a problem for my device, as it is for many, I can tolerate a charge pump efficiency that is somewhat less than the state of the art.  So I have been thinking about a discrete design using a 555 timer and external "medium current" switches (BJTs,...)

The other thing that I can tolerate and is actually helpful, is lower than "state of the art" charge-pump switching speeds.  I need to be quiet in the 100MHz range.

I have some design flexibility, but would love to start from point of SE wisdom.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: $0.02 thought.  If you can't find a magnet-free fan, can you bring in cooling air via a plastic tube from a safe distance?

Comment: a 555 will blow your power budget.

Comment: are air-core inductors allowed?

Comment: 5 volts at 500 uA is a power of 2.5 mW - why should this be regarded as problematic heat wise for an LDO regulator?

Comment: Such teensy current.  Are non-magnetic inductors or capacitor based pulse methods like a voltage multiplier acceptable?

Comment: Andy:  I totally put uA when I meant mA.  I do know the diff :)  I fixed the post.

Comment: No inductors will work at 3 Tesla. We have talked about a tube in the past, but it needs an air source and punches another hole in the Faraday cage that is the MRI room. Steel tanks of air or nitrogen don't go well inside a 3T MRI room. Ballistic missile.

Comment: A gyrator is a non-magnetic inductor, so it would perform the same as an inductor electrically but work in your environment at least as well as op amps, resistors and capacitors will.  If you actually only needed 500 microamps they might have been ok, but the main disadvantage is high R so at 500mA I don't think they'd apply.  Really interesting sets of accommodations you have to make though.  What about capacitor based methods of stepping down the voltage though?  If you're allowed capacitors you can be more efficient than an LDO.  Have you ever been around during an unplanned magnet quench?

Comment: KH:  I never have but I've seen some crazy pictures of MRI "disasters"  glad I never caused any of them. (at least not yet :)  ------ I'll read about gyrators.  You are on the right track here.  What I'm really asking is how do this with all capacitors.  I've even considered leveraging the 2 Ohm BNC cable that can take some of the heat and voltage drop for topping off a cap.  Just can't figure out the right combination of ideas.  How do you see stepping down voltage using capacitors different from what I would call a charge pump?

Comment: From WikiPedia: Simulated inductors (gyrator is an example) do not have the inherent energy storing properties of the real inductors and this limits the possible power applications